# Excel truncates string data to 255 symbols. How I can read the whole string data without changing the registry

Tags: c#, excel, com

As you know Excel truncates string data if you try to read it. Microsoft says one has to set `TypeGuessRows` to 0 in the registry. But I am not allowed to change it there (customer restriction).
I tried to write this parameter in the connection string like this

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0"""
```

but it doesn't work.

The question is: how I can read the whole string data from the Excel file without changing the `TypeGuessRows` parameter?
Are there any other ways to solve this problem? I can use Excel via interop...

Comment: Use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **ACE Driver** instead of JET (it's available on x86 and x64 servers, JET is only x86!)

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

Answer (score 0):

No the problem isn't an excel one; it's the JET driver so the only way to change it is in the registry as you've mentioned